# .replace not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'div[id^="button-"]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var elementId = event.target.id.replace(/\D/g,'');
        $(".content-wrapper-" + elementId).css("display","inline");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="button-1"></div>
<div id="button-2"></div>
<div id="button-3"></div>

<div class="content-wrapper-1" style="display: none;">Test 1</div>
<div class="content-wrapper-2" style="display: none;">Test 2</div>
<div class="content-wrapper-3" style="display: none;">Test 3</div>
```

**QUICK EXPLANATION**

Get the ID of the clicked element and extract all the numbers. For example "button-9" to "9". Afterwards concatenat the string .content-wrapper + ID and display the contents of that container.*

This is working in Google Chrome but not in Firefox. I could break it down to this line:

```
var elementId = event.target.id.replace(/\D/g,'');
```

but i can not figure out whats wrong here. A little help woud be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line assumes `event` exists as a global variable:

```
event.target.id.replace(/\D/g,'');
^^^^^
```

This is [a non-standard property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) and is not supported in Firefox. You already have access to the event as the first argument to your callback:

```
e.target.id.replace(/\D/g,'');
^
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

`event` is global in `chrome` and `IE` but not in firefox it defined in fucntion, so Replace `event` to `e`, to make it work in all browsers.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'div[id^="button-"]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var elementId = e.target.id.replace(/\D/g,'');
        $(".content-wrapper-" + elementId).css("display","inline");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
HTML

<div id="button-1">11</div>
<div id="button-2">22</div>
<div id="button-3">33</div>

<div class="content-wrapper-1" style="display: none;">Test 1</div>
<div class="content-wrapper-2" style="display: none;">Test 2</div>
<div class="content-wrapper-3" style="display: none;">Test 3</div>
```